# How to get user phone number in palm webOS

Tags: webos, palm

i am going to develop an application in palm webOS, for that i need to get phone number from device. Is it possible to get phone number?. please help me to get phone number from palm device. ThanQ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the nuid.  Not sure if that will be useful for your app:

http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1550

Answer (score 2):

There is no way through the use of the official APIs to get that information, just like accessing contacts emails, this would allow potential misuse.