# How to get Palm Mobile Owner information?

Tags: webos, palm

How can i get Palm mobile owner information like name/phone number/mailId ..... from code itself.
Thaq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525174/how-to-get-user-phone-number-in-palm-webos), this is not possible, as it would allow potential misuse.

Comment: Interesting that the source of both questions is the same... ;-)